# Is it possible to do mathematics inside CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jquery accorion id `#accordion` and some of the content inside header class name `.simpleColor`. Now I want to give a calculated margin to .simpleColor. In pseudo...it looks something like this,

```
.simpleClass {
    margin-left: ((#accordion.width/2) - (.simpleColor.width/2));
}
```

I am open to use any other technology such as javascript to achieve this if it is possible.

Comment: That looks like you want to center something horizontally. Have you tried `margin: 0 auto;`?

Comment: Have you heard of [calc()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc0)

Comment: Nope never...sounds seems helpful

Comment: CSS-Tricks article: [Logical Operations with CSS Variables](https://css-tricks.com/logical-operations-with-css-variables/)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There's a CSS function called [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) that is starting to get pretty good support. The syntax works as followed:

```
width: calc(50% - 100px);
```

(Note that the whitespace around the operators is significant)

This allows true dynamic computational support in CSS. With a preprocessor, you can only combine static lengths with static lengths, and relative lengths with relative ones.

At this point in time calc has achieved widespread support and should be safe to use unless you have specific needs for supporting legacy browsers.

Comment: Works perfectly across Chrome, Firefox and IE as you mentioned on Win7 and 8. Thanks!

Getting padding and a 100% width div has been such a pain, and using javascript for something so simple seemed like a waste.  This is much better!

Comment: You might want to also look into [`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) as well. That makes padding subtract from the width instead of adding it, and it has better support than calc, back to IE8, and has a [polyfill available for IE6/7](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill) if support is needed. IE8 still has a sizeable market share, so I recommend using `box-sizing` for your needs.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to do mathematic operations inside CSS natively.  You could use JavaScript to change CSS properties on page load, but this is a pain and must be done every page load making your page slow.

You'll need to use a CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#-operations), [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/), or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

The bonus to using either of these languages is that you can generate actual CSS stylesheets from them.  You also get benefits like functions, mixins, variable, and more.

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery('.simpleClass').css('margin-left', (jQuery('#accordian').width() / 2) - (jQuery('.simpleColor').width() / 2) + 'px');
```

Should do what you are wanting.  But you need to do something like this in javascript, you can't do it in pure CSS unless the widths for #accordian and .simpleColor are known in advance (and thus calculated in advance).

Answer (score 2):

You can do maths in CSS e.g.:

`height: calc(100% - 20%);`

CSS will also handle the different units, so this works too:

`height: calc(100% - 20px);`

Additionally, [**min()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min), [**max()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max) and [**clamp()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp) have also been added allowing for calculations like this:

`height: min(calc(100% - 20px), 50%);`

1. **min()**: gets the minimum value;
2. **max()**: gets the maximum value; and
3. **clamp()**: limits a value by providing an upper and lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the CSS should be pure style definition. I dont like to mix some calculations with that. I would do that in my javascript

```
var accWidth=parseInt($("#accordion").css("width").replace("px",""));
var simpWidth=parseInt($(".simpleColor").css("width").replace("px",""));
var marginLeft=((accWidth/2)-(simpWidth/2));       
$(".simpleClass").css("margin-left",marginLeft);
```

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/mzTRw/19/

Comment: Instead of parseInt($("#accordion").css("width").replace("px","")) you can just use $("#accordion").width() to get the integer value.