# Is there a way to calculate in CSS?

Tags: html, css

**I am studying CSS and I have a question, is there a way to calculate in pure CSS?**

Let's say a basic calculation, 100% - 50px. I don't want to use Javascript even though that is a simple way of doing it. I want to keep my code nice and clean. I thought maybe it would be possible to write something like this :

```
width: 100% - 50px;
```

But it didn't work. I'm starting to lean towards using Javascript, but I would rather not.

Comment: Try using SASS, i know it has calculations, however 100% and 50px are two completely different units of measurement so i'm not sure if it'd work how you'd like

Comment: Use `calc()`. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378292/is-it-possible-to-do-mathematics-inside-css)

Comment: If you can't or don't want to use `calc()` then you usually can usually avoid it by restructuring your HTML and CSS. In that case you'd have to show a more complete example of what you are doing.

Comment: try using SASS ... but pure CSS2 does not allow calculation of that type... CSS3 may have something, but it is not widely supported... you cannot have a clean code and at the same time work on every browser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `calc()` in supporting browsers:

```
width: calc(100% - 50px);
```

References:

- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) (MDN).
- [`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation) (W3C).
- [`calc()` compatibility](http://caniuse.com/calc).

Comment: calc() is not widely supported

Comment: @florin: indeed, but it remains the only css means of fulfilling the requirements of the question, and I've added a link to compatibility to address that.

Comment: I disagree, `calc' is quite well supported IE9+up, Chrome, FF, Safari, Opera (not Mini) - [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Comment: i understand you David, i voted you Up, i just wanted to warn the question owner that he may expect compatibility issues... thank you for the edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
width: calc(100% + 12px);
width: -webkit-calc(100% + 12px);
width: -moz-calc(100% + 12px);
```

or

```
width: calc(100% - 12px);
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 12px);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 12px);
```