# In CSS, calculate 'px' based padding as a percentage of an element that has 100% width

Tags: css

I have the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mobile-container">
Hello World!
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mobile-container{
width:100%;
padding:50px;
}
```

How do I convert the '50px' padding into a percentage. As the device's viewport increases in width, I want the padding to proportionally increase. But, the real reason, I want to know what the value is, as a percentage, is that I will then be able to calculate the width of the element minus the padding, as a percentage. This will allow me to assign  'vw' units for the text inside the element.

Comment: With Javascript.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. Can't you just set the padding to a percentage [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/zp5ajsyf/1/)?

Comment: Yes. I could just give the padding an arbitary value or I could use javascript as suggested, by using the 'px' value of the viewport to work out what 50px is as a %. Or I could use the smallest possible mobile device width of 320px to work out what 50px is, as a %. I just wondered whether there was a definitve answer?

Comment: Oh I see. You want the calculated value to be 50px, but defined as a percentage? Since the padding changes with the width, I think you'd need to define at what width the padding will be 50px. For example, at 500px wide the padding will be 50px. Again, I might still be misunderstanding what you're aiming for.

Comment: Yes. I think you are right. I need to define a benchmark width to calculate the % against. I thought about using 320px as the width. But, actually what I really wanted was to emulate the javascript solution via CSS?

Comment: With javascript, I would grab the viewport width in 'px' and then I can work out what 50px is, as a %. Can this be achieved using CSS?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that with pure CSS (yet), but maybe with a CSS preprocessor and definitely with JavaScript. You might find this post helpful: [Is it possible to do mathematics inside CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378292/is-it-possible-to-do-mathematics-inside-css)

Comment: Thanks for this. I think the key part, is to be able to read the viewport width in 'px' via CSS...